# Unable to connect to Azure Storage Table resource using SAS key

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-explorer

I have been provided SAS key for an Azure Storage Table resource and I am trying to connect to that using Azure Storage Explorer but keep getting the error:-

```
Error occurred while adding new connection: SyntaxError:Table name format is incorrect.
```

I even updated Azure Storage Explorer version but the issue is still the same. The SAS key is correct. And in fact for none of the Azure Storage Table resources I have been able to connect using SAS key while using Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: Can you share the SAS URL? Please obfuscate account name and sig portion of your SAS URL.

Comment: https://<accountname>.table.core.windows.net/<azurestoragetablename>?sv=tokensignature

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the full SAS Token. Can you share the complete SAS Token (the whole thing after `?` in your SAS URL?

Comment: Here is the whole thing after ?:-     sv=2018-03-28&tn=<azurestoragetablename>&si=<somemaskedstring>&sig=hTiyKZYjqsykksv4iz1%2FKn6epkmtJP3OD2iyDwN5FnQ%3D. I have still masked the table name as it appeared here and also some business related string as <somemarkedstring> and also filled some characters in the actual signature (e.g. if it is T make it P) -- so you know actual form and still privacy of the url is maintained. Hope this gives you the info you need.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is weird. I created a SAS token for one of the tables in my storage account and I was able to connect using Storage Explorer. Here's my SAS URL looks like: `https://<account>.table.core.windows.net/<table-name>?sv=2018-03-28&si=A&tn=<table-name>&sig=%2Ff%2BlfzVd2XKhbKm4p2E%2Bt2e2HjOqzYbvn6fuC10ltac%3D`

Comment: @GauravMantri can you pls try to specify incorrect table name (but correct storage name) and see if you get exact same error I got? I don't have access to the subscription that has this table so I can't even verify if there is a typo in the table name -- but then I generated SAS key for the table I have subscription access to and even that when I specify in Storage Explorer , I get the same error. So something to do with Storage Explorer. Also others in the team are able to reproduce this error so it's not just me.

Comment: Nope. Even with incorrect table name, I am able to connect. I used version 1.12.0 on Mac.

Comment: I looked up the source code for Storage Explorer and reason for this error is invalid table name. I'm not sure if you can share the name of the table for me to take a look but that's where the problem is.

Comment: you mean the table with that name doesn't exist ? because this is merely SAS key created for the table. But then I have access to some other tables under my subscription and I generated SAS key for them myself just to test and even for them I got the same error through storage explorer.

Comment: Can you try by creating a table with name as “test” and create a SAS URL for that and connect using this URL. You should not get any errors.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this scenario because the SAS key that I was originally trying was for a specific table -- now I have created at table in my storage account but not able to create SAS key specifically for this table -- it is generating SAS key for the whole storage , don't see any option to only select specific table

Comment: You can connect to your storage account using account name/key in Storage Explorer and there you should be able to create a SAS URL for a table. If you can share the name of the table, I can try in my storage account as I think the problem is with table name.

Comment: there is no issue with the table name , I was able to create table with the same name against my storage account successfully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211474/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-dhiraj).